# PrimeFaces Datatable - What is f:facet actually doing?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

Looking through some PrimeFaces code in an app I noticed the following line:

```
<f:facet name="header">#{trainSearch.trainCount} Trains</f:facet>
```

It looks like it is overriding the header, which makes sense, but can someone explain this to me in a little more detail?

What is actually happening with this line of code?

Complete code listed below:

```
           <p:dataTable id = "results" value = "#{trainSearch.trains}" var = "train"     rendered="#{not empty trainSearch.trains}" styleClass = "train-search-table horizontal-border">
                <f:facet name="header">#{trainSearch.trainCount} Trains</f:facet> 
                <p:column headerText = "Train ID">
                    <p:panelGrid columns="1" styleClass = "train-id-grid" layout = "grid">
                        <h:outputText styleClass = "train-id-label" value="#{train.trainI}"/>
                        <h:outputText value="#{train.originCityState} > #{train.destinationCityState}" />
                    </p:panelGrid>
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Scheduled Departure">
                    <h:outputText value="#{train.formattedScheduledDepartureText}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Scheduled Arrival">
                    <h:outputText value="#{train.formattedScheduledArrivalText}" />
                </p:column>
                 <p:column headerText="Loco Count">
                    <h:outputText value="#{train.locoCount}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Car Count">
                    <h:outputText value="#{train.carCount}" />
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Facets in JSF are used to customize the rendering of a component, without touching its code, like the header facet in datatable, where you can put custom code in datatable header, without touching actual PrimeFaces datatable code.

The `DataTableRenderer` (class that writes html code of datatable) gets the xhtml code you put inside a facet and renders it inside a div.

You can see this in the method `encodeFacet`of `DataTableRenderer`:

```
protected void encodeFacet(FacesContext context, DataTable table, UIComponent facet, String styleClass) throws IOException {
    if(facet == null)
        return;

    ResponseWriter writer = context.getResponseWriter();

    writer.startElement("div", null);
    writer.writeAttribute("class", styleClass, null);

    facet.encodeAll(context);

    writer.endElement("div");
}
```

The line `facet.encodeAll(context);` renders the code you put inside facet as html, in RENDER_RESPONSE jsf phase.